# Checking a json api output for changes using python

Tags: python, json, urllib, twitch

I am attempting to build a small script to check twitch for followers and alert when someone new follows. Here is what I have so far:

```
import urllib,json

url = 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/tilt41/follows?direction=ASC&limit=1&offset=0'
response = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = json.load(response)
fname = data['follows'][0]['user']['display_name']

print "New follower: "+fname
```

Where I am stuck is I am not sure on how to only output when the value changes.
Is there a specific way to save the first output and use that to check every 5 to 10 seconds if the value has change? And if the value changes I want to print the new value and save over the old.

Comment: You'll want to have a closer look at the response headers and read up on [ETags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag) in order to do a conditional GET request. If you just keep doing a full GET request every 5-10 seconds (!), then you'll surely either hit a rate limit or get banned outright. Once you get that right, keeping track of the followers should be the easy part. As it stands, your question is simply to broad, sorry.

Comment: ok thank you I will look into that and see if I can give a better question

Comment: @Redstone I wrote a similar app when I started streaming on Twitch that I can't seem to track down right now. Thought I had it on github but I guess I neglected to use VCS on this little throwaway project. I'll grab it later and link you. For the record, I didn't use ETags either, and have no idea if Twitch's API uses them or not

Comment: @Redstone you'll find the link to the repo [here](https://github.com/NotTheEconomist/twitch_followers). I also rolled in a bit of integration with Pushbullet so I got phone notifications when I had a new follower. Note that all the information I can find says that Twitch both [*does not* do a hard rate limit if you send your client_id in the headers](https://discuss.dev.twitch.tv/t/rate-limit-question-twitchalerts-dev/1048) and also that they're expecting [about 1 request per second per app](https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API/issues/50)